# How to report an author who doesn't share the last name but had similar first name as mine, is adding my articles in his profile on google scholar?

Tags: publications, ethics

Recently, I got to know that a person who doesn't share the last name but had a similar first name as mine, is adding my articles in his profile. Ironically, my most recent published article didn't appear in my profile, but it already appears in his profile. When I inquired and requested him to remove my articles from his profile, he just ignores my emails. 
How to handle is the situation? I found his LinkedIn profile, should I contact his school?
 How one can trust the "google scholar profile" of a researcher; especially if it's that simple to add other person's work and there is no way to report or flag fraud etc. 
This man has 8000+ citation; who knows he is adding other people articles, maybe to achieve some short term goals.

Comment: I realize it's frustrating, but do note that it's within the realm of possibility that he let's Google Scholar update his profile automatically, and that he didn't see your emails. Also consider if you can include a middle initial in your publications going forward, in order to reduce the risk of getting confused with different authors.

Comment: @Anyon I always add my first and last name, his first name is same with me, not the last name. I am surprised how google can automatically add article just based on same first name. I always use my email of my institution and this person has verified email of his institution on google scholar. This is making me suspicious as he is doing intentionally.

Comment: I see. I assumed you shared the same last name - and had similar first names (as you write in the title, but not the post). It'd be good if you could edit your question to make this clearer.

Comment: Why downvoted? Instead of just downvote, please share your opinion if there is something wrong with this question.

Comment: @Anyon thanks! I updated the question

Comment: Maybe it is an issue you can clean up much faster with Google as the admin of Google Scholar instead of the other person.

Comment: 'How one can trust the "google scholar profile" of a researcher' You can't. I have never even looked if I have one and it's possible this person hasn't either. My boss became a Clarivate "highly cited researcher" some years ago and I had to show him how to remove wrongly linked publications from his profiles (he was still "highly cited" thereafter).

Answer (score 4):

Don't assume malice. It appears to be unlikely that this person is doing this actively. The more likely scenario is that Google's algorithms add these publications to their profile automatically and they are not maintaining the profile at all. Since they don't care about Google Scholar and are probably the typical busy professor, your attempts at contacting them about it are just filtered out as noise with hundreds of other emails.

If you really care about this, you'll probably need to address this issue to Google (but according to other posts on the internet they seem to be known to not care and to not fix).